# Start cmd and run multiple commands in the created cmd instance

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to start cmd window and then running a chain of cmds in succession one after the other in that cmd window.
something like `start cmd /k pipenv shell && py manage.py runserver` the start cmd should open a new cmd window, which actually happens, then the pipenv shell should start a virtual environment within that cmd instance, also happens, and the `py manage.py runserver` should run in the created environment but instead it runs where the script is called.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: A simple caret solves this `start cmd /k pipenv shell && py manage.py runserverstart cmd /k pipenv shell ^&^& py manage.py runserver` , but it's easier to use a batch file

Comment: the caret seems not change anything

Comment: I missed the first `&&`, it should be `cmd /k pipenv shell ^&^& py manage.py runserverstart cmd /k pipenv shell ^&^& py manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2):

When issuing commands chaining them, the system sees it as `first command && second command`

I your case, you are giving first command to be `start cmd` and second command `py manage.py` which will do exactly that, you are issuing a cmd in a new window and if that is successful, it will initiate `py` in the same window you started. You should therefore escape the `&` with a caret in order to pass through the chain to the second command window and not initiate the chain in the current window:

```
start cmd /k pipenv shell ^&^& py manage.py runserver
```

Keep in mind that you could also just add both commands into a batch file as:

```
pipenv shell
py manage.py runserver
```

and launch it as:

```
start "" mybatch.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `py manage.py runserver` command calling python executor in your major environment. In your case, you could use `pipenv run manage.py runserver` that detect your virtual env inside your pipfile and activate it to run your command. An alternative way is to use `virtualenv` that create virtual env directly inside your project directory and calling `envname\Scripts\activate` each time you want to run something inside your virtual env.

Comment: removes the need to run two successive commands, that's y I have voted you up though it does not solve my problem of wanting to run successive scripts in opened cmd, I have other cmds commands i want to run in succession other than the virtual environment