# How to start cmd from within powershell and pass a command to the cmd instance?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to create an instance of a windows cmd terminal from powershell every minute for a maximum of 8 times and get each cmd instance to run a nodejs script from there.

Here is my code so far:

```
For ($i=0; $i -le 8; $i++) {
    start cmd.exe /k node index.js
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
```

but I keep on getting errors:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'node'.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\x\x\build\src\start.ps1:2 char:5
+     start cmd.exe /k node index.js
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I have already looked at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1258514/how-from-a-cmd-start-a-new-cmd-instance-and-run-a-command-within/1258521#1258521?newreg=cb8933eb97414fbb8f2b2a18ee920883) answer posted on SuperUser, however, it is not clear to me what I am doing wrong.

The second answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941842/start-cmd-and-run-multiple-commands-in-the-created-cmd-instance) stack overflow thread seems to be doing exactly what I am trying to do, but I keep getting the above error.

Comment: try `cmd.exe /k "node index.js"` without the start cmdlet.

Comment: `start` is an alias in PowerShell for `Start-Process`. Have you reviewed the information from `help Start-Process -Full`? What version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Unfortunately that doesnt work, because it does not create a new instance of cmd in a new window like it would if it had the ```start``` before it

Comment: See especially `help Start-Process -Full` Example 7 in PowerShell 7.1.2.

Comment: Similar to Abrahams comment, I would probably try replacing `start cmd.exe /k node index.js` with `& cmd /D /K "node index.js"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start** is an alias for the **Start-Process** cmdlet as mentioned by @lit

Any arguments have to passed on with the **-ArgumentList** parameter.

```
start "cmd.exe"  -ArgumentList "/k node index.js"
```